# How do I remove an installed .pkg file

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, driver, pkg

I recently installed this "CH341 Driver" so that I could connect my new chinese Arduino.

But when I plug the USB cable, connected to the Arduino, into my computer it crashes immediately. A few moments later a message pops up that tells me that, because of a problem, the computer had to restart.

Now I want to delete this installed driver and download another driver or another version of it. But in order to do so I need to delete the old software (which makes my computer crash).

I looked around on the internet about how to do so, but most of the googled suggestions tell me that I can simply remove it from the "Applications" folder. It isn't a program so that won't help. I also found a few results that tell me to open terminal, enter the command "pkgutil --pkgs", search for the package and enter the command "sudo pkgutil --forget the-package-name.pkg".

But I can't find the package name in the list. So I went to "About this Mac" -> "System Report..." -> "Software" -> "Installations" and there I can see the names of the packages, but unfortunately I can't remove them from there.

So is there anybody who can tell me where I can remove them?

Answer (score 5):

You can check what was installed and remove it manually. Copy the `*.pkg` file to some empty tmp folder. Then:

```
xar -xf YOUPACKAGE.pkg
```

Then print the content of the `Bom` file with:

```
 lsbom $(find . -name Bom)
```

You'll have the list of files like: (Here's the part for Cisco AnyConnect)

```
./opt/cisco/vpn 40755   0/0
./opt/cisco/vpn/bin 40755   0/0
```

All file path start with `.` but they are installed relative to the root folder (`/`). In my example I have to remove `/opt/cisco` folder.

Comment: You could also use [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com) to visually show you the contents of package and receipt files, and scan for receipt files for particular applications... though unfortunately it has no uninstall capability, which I always thought would be useful.

Comment: Just an fyi... The output of my lsbom command seemed to reference ~/Library. Not sure why - I was trying to uninstall the Skype Web Plugin on OSX 10.11.6

Answer (score -1):

I removed the `.pkg` file from its installation path `/Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext`.